# Is P(D | A) = P(D | A,B) * P(B | A) according to the Bayesian Network in the description?

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, bayesian-network

if I consider the Bayesian network in the picture below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZKN2.jpg
So A is the parent of C,D and B. But B is also the parent of D. Is it then correct to write: P(D | A) = P(D | A,B) * P(B | A)?

Also, if I hav this formula for the full joint probability P(A,B,C,D) = P(D | A,B) * P(B | A) *P(C | A) * P(A), how can I know the number of parameters required to specify this probability? I have been looking for the rules on the internet but I keep getting confused. Is it (3*3*3)+(3*3)+(3*3)+2=47 parameters?
Would appreciate the feedback!